# How to add radio button drawable from web url

Tags: android, android-glide

I use Glide for networking and loading all the images. But that works for imageviews. How do I load an image and set it up as radio button drawable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom `Target`. See the wiki article: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets. In `onResourceReady` you can use the loaded `Bitmap` or `Drawable` however you wish. Be sure to stop using the resource when `onLoadCleared` or `onLoadFailed` are called though!